# How do I get 50 Reputation?

Tags: discussion

I was going to comment that the atmosphere takes about 1/3 to 1/2 the mussel velocity based on my 1987 paper on the Flight of Passive Launch Vehicles. I am about to re-do the paper and am working from memory.

I try but get the note I need 50 Reputation to do so.

How do I get this reputation to do so? If it is more than a day’s work forget it and don’t reply this email. This is in relation to sweep / survey research (who’s doing work in the field now) not home base research to me.

Yours truly,

Ed Wilson, P. Eng., M.Sc., P.E.

Comment: See: http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Answer questions on the site. It could be one days work, could be one hours work. Depends on the quality of the post(s).

Comment: Welcome to Physics (and the Physics meta site). As long as we're doing "Welcome to the site!" things, I should mention that signature in the post are discouraged, but that you can fill out the About Me box in your profile with essentially anything you want.

Comment: You didn't link to the question, but it sounds from this post you have enough content to answer.  Answers do not take any reputation, and a good one will bring you a bunch.  It sounds like you have valuable information to contribute, which will encourage upvotes on an answer if you choose to post one.

Comment: "mussel velocity"? Your question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Ask questions about physics, or answer them: people upvote your posts to give you reputation. It should take less than 10 decent posts to get 50 reputation. Note: the amount of upvotes you get and hence reputation is as much related to how popular the question is as how good of an answer you give and whether there are competing answers.

Answer (score 3):

Pick a tag you know something about (fluid mechanics perhaps?). Find an interesting question that you can answer. Write a good answer (diagrams, references). See if comments / questions come back. Respond, improve your answer. If you pick up just four upvotes and an accept you will collect 55 rep points.

That may not happen with your first or second answer but soon you will hit a good one.

Half an hour a day for three days ought to be more than enough if you follow the site rules (be polite etc).